# Can't use PyTorch in PyCharm

Tags: package-management, python, anaconda, pycharm, conda

I installed PyTorch via Anaconda and changed the Project interpreter to Conda Environment in the settings in PyCharm.

Even though I can request the PyTorch version in the console with

```
import torch
print(torch.__version__)
```

it doesn't work in PyCharm.

The response I get is

```
/home/felix/anaconda3/envs/untitled2/bin/python /home/felix/PycharmProjects/untitled2/k
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/felix/PycharmProjects/untitled2/k", line 1, in <module>
    import torch
  File "/home/felix/anaconda3/envs/untitled2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 102, in <module>
    from torch._C import *
ImportError: /home/felix/anaconda3/envs/untitled2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch.so.1: undefined symbol: nvrtcGetProgramLogSize

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Does anybody know how to fix this issue? I'm a linux beginner so maybe I made a fundamental mistake.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You made a fundamental mistake. PyTorch is hard to install even without Anaconda to make it even harder. Anaconda is a luxury that you don't need.

Comment: But if I made a fundamental mistake during PyTorch installation it wouldn't work in the Terminal neither, would it?

Comment: Anaconda makes everything go to hell except itself.

Comment: Okay, I'm using a VM because I thought something like that could happen. Would you advise me to set up a new VM and install PyTorch without Anaconda? Do I need anything else to install PyTorch, like NumPy, ...

Comment: You also need to install Numpy (`sudo apt install python3-numpy`).